# Error : JAVA_HOME is pointing to invalid version of java while Installing Maximo Anywhere 7.6.2 on MAC OSX

Tags: macos, java-home, maximo

I am trying to install Maximo Anywhere 7.6.2 on MAC OSX by referring to documentation on ibm site below :
Maximo_Anywhere_7_6_1_Installation_Start_to_Finish.pdf

On my mac I have  jdk1.8.0_131.jdk  which is set as  export  JAVA_HOME  as well as in ~/.bash_profile.

But  IBM installation manager has taken  jre version 
as  " Java SE 1.7.0_111". I verified it in /Applications/IBM/InstallationManager/eclipse/jre_7.0.90060.20161108_1344

So when I try to Install IBM Anywhere component using IBM installation manager 
i get the error 
[image]

I referred to [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21982195) IBM support link but it is not working.

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just struggled with identical problem. In case of MacOS installation simple ​`export JAVA_HOME=...` may not be sufficient due to default sudo security restrictions (at least this was the case on my MacOS 10.12).
​By default `sudo` environment inherits only subset of current process environment variables. There is no *JAVA_HOME* among them so when you start Installation Manager it will fail at one of the first prerequisites checks with following error:

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is pointing to an invalid version of Java. Install Oracle JDK and update the JAVA_HOME environment variable to contain the path of the JDK installation directory.                                                              
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is pointing to a directory that does not contain a java that was vended by Oracle Corporation or SunMicrosystems Inc.
Update JAVA_HOME so that java.vendor is set to either Oracle Corporation or Sun Microsystems Inc.
```

Solution to this problem is to edit sodoers file (`sudo visudo`) and add one more line to `Defaults` section. In my case it was:

```
##
## Defaults specification
##

Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE"
Defaults    env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM"
[...]
# Newly added line
Defaults    env_keep += "JAVA_HOME"
```

Once this was done installation went smoothly.

Comment: Thanks a lot  user3747781. Your solution helped me resolve JAVA_HOME issue on mac . I used command  sudo EDITOR=nano visudo. When I continue with the installation , at next step it says No Provisioning profile  found.Where do we need to set the provisioning profile? Do we need to set provisioning profile  at installation stage itself?